AWS dynamodb list-backups responds with empty result
I've set up a backup plan, where my dynamodb table is backed-up and copied to the another region
Both backup and copy jobs completed successfully, in DynamoDB AWS console in target region I could see there is a backup available, however, when I run the following aws command - aws dynamodb list-backups --region <target_region> --backup-type AWS_BACKUP, I do see an empty response. I also tried several variations of using --backup-type flag, but none helped.
One more interesting thing is that, in a source region, from which the backup was copied from, the command mentioned above didn't work as well. However, just before I did setup a backup plan with advanced feature disabled (hence, copying to a different region was disabled as well), and command above worked
Is there any reason for such weird behaviour?
Thanks in advance!
I expect on aws dynamodb list-backups --region <target_region> --backup-type AWS_BACKUP command to get the list of backups for my dynamodb table

Help for that awscli command states: "List DynamoDB backups that are associated with an Amazon Web Services account and weren't made with Amazon Web Services Backup." If you used AWS Backup, rather than DynamoDB's native featres, then use aws backup list...

@jarmod okay but ... Why did it work before then? Just before I enabled advanced features in AWS Backup console (makes me confused). It is fine I can't get it with aws dynamodb, I can get it with aws backup list-recovery-points-by-resource ..., but just interesting

Help for aws dynamodb list-backups states:

List DynamoDB backups that are associated with an Amazon Web Services account and weren't made with Amazon Web Services Backup.

AWS Backup offers enhanced backup features such as cross-account and cross-region copying  plus cold storage tiering that aren't part of the native DynamoDB feature set. Use aws backup ... to manage the former, enhanced features. They're features of AWS Backup, not of Amazon DynamoDB.
